# For loop with two database queries in Twig

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim, twig-extension

I'd really love if anyone can help, I'm trying to figure out a way to loop through two queries in Twig. I can create it in PHP but I'm having doing the same thing on Twig. This is how I'd normally do it on PHP:

```
foreach($items as $item){
   $product_id = $item;
   $products = $app->db->table('products')->where('id', $product_id)->first();
   echo "<li>" . $products->title . "</li>";
}
```

The above code will work fine but on Twig it will not loop to the next loop, but it will keep on looping the same thing.
Kindly help if you know how I can use Twig for loop like I use it above. I'm querying it using Laravel Eloquent in Slim.

This is what I did:

**The controller**

```
$products = $app->db->table('products')->where('trash', '0')->first();
```

**The View**

```
{% for item in items %}
      {% set product_id = item.id %}
       <li> {{ products.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

It will only show the first row and repeat the samething.

Comment: Share your Twig code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt to run queries from a template. Do it in the controller and pass the result to the template.

Also `$items` appears to be an array of IDs, so you should be able to load all of the products at once with a where-in condition (instead of multiple queries):

Controller:

```
$products = $app->db->table('products')->whereIn('id', $items)->get();

// pass $products to the template as "products"
```

Twig template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <li>{{ product.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to run two queries $items a json decoded from the 1st query in the controller, and $products where I only want to query the first row in products it works well in php but in twig only for the first query and not the next loop.

Comment: actually you should not run the queries on the controller level either, but rather in the data layer, i.e 'Model' ideally using a service to abstract the data layer from the controller

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov Expanding upon this idea, you should be using `traits` within your model to handle the interaction with a `ModelRepository` where the real data manipulation occurs. This makes the entire routine accessible through the Service Layer when running Unit Tests. Super important.

Comment: Thank you so much guys it worked. I think I will continue and using Twig.